# How to use the canvas scale method in javascript with the implementation a coodinates remaping

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, vector-graphics, coordinate-systems

I have a simple HTML canvas and a JavaScript that draws something on it. The problem is that, I implemented a remapping function that converts `xOy` orthogonal coordinates system to screen coordinates because I want to do something related to 2D euclidian geometry:
So, the (0, 0) isn't on the left upper corner, but in the middle:

```
//canvasPos is a custom class(Vector2) with 2 fields, x and y. This parameters stores the
//pixel coordinates in xOy coordinates.
function convertCoordinates(canvasPos, width, height){
    return new Vector2(canvasPos.x + width / 2, Math.abs(canvasPos.y-height/2));
}
```

for example calling the function with:

```
let test = convertCoordinates(new Vector2(0, 0), 200, 200);
console.log("(" + test.x + ", " + test.y + ")"); //outputs "(100, 100)"
```

```
let test = convertCoordinates(new Vector2(-100, 100), 200, 200);
console.log("(" + test.x + ", " + test.y + ")"); //outputs "(0, 0)"
```

```
let test = convertCoordinates(new Vector2(100, 100), 200, 200);
console.log("(" + test.x + ", " + test.y + ")"); //outputs "(200, 0)"
```

And I also created a drawLine function:

```
function drawLine(ctx, from, to) {    
    let width = ctx.canvas.clientWidth;
    let height = ctx.canvas.clientHeight;
    let c1 = convertCoordinates(from, width, height);
    let c2 = convertCoordinates(to, width, height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(c1.x, c1.y);
    ctx.lineTo(c2.x, c2.y);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Now I can draw a line using the coordinates system we all learn in middle school(I need this because it is some kind of tutorial related to basic geometry)

Now, the problem is that everything I draw is very low resolution(text, lines, elipses, etc). I searched online and there are many Stack OverFlow threads on this subject, however most of the solutions include scaling the canvas context up, and then scaling it down using "ctx.scale();".
Others include creating a buffering bitmap and then drawing it pixel by pixel, however every solution I try to sharpen the drawings on canvas seems to ruin my convertCoordinates function, the conversion gets messed up when I use ctx.scale(), or ctx.translate().

Comment: Do you get this resolution issue only when you started mapping coordinates systems ? alson It may be silly but are your browser OR your Operating System having any Zoom activated ?